# getting springboot to support groovy 4.0 (apache packaging) | needed 3.0.0-M2 and more

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, spring-initializr

spring-boot > 2.3.1 will grab groovy-bom from codehaus instead of org.apache.groovy packaging, even if you declare org.apache.groovy dependendices

I found this means spring-boot > 2.3.1 will not build groovy 4.0

even spring initializr bakes this in... because when you go springboot 2.6.7, initializr is using groovy packaging from org.codehaus. so that limits 2.6.7 to use groovy 3.0.10, as that's the cutoff for groovy to show up in org.apache packaging. and groovy 4.x uses apache packages.

here's the gradle [initializr created from this URL](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=groovy&platformVersion=2.6.7&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-rest,data-jpa)

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.7'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
  id 'groovy'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
  implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Andy Wilkinson's tip, I started exploring springboot 3.0.0-M2. I got my spring-data-rest application to build and to run using groovy 4.0.2. but it took some source code changes because of jpa annotations moving to jakarta packaging. I provide the solution, including some lines commented out so you can see what was replaced.

Comment: I relied on the following [documentation from Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M2/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#introduction)

Answer (score 1):

Support for Groovy 4 is coming in Spring Framework 6 and Spring Boot 3. It’s currently available in Spring Boot 3.0.0-M2 which is published to https://repo.spring.io/milestone.

Comment: I will look into it, and update what I find. thanks for the tip.

Comment: it took some doing, but I finally got a springboot 3.0.0-M2 to build and run with groovy 4.0.2. I will update the original post shortly

Answer (score 0):

you 1st have to change settings.gradle to add the following:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Then I had to modify my build.gradle as follows:

```
plugins {
//    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'groovy'
}
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0-M2'
}


group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = javaSrcVersion
targetCompatibility = javaClassVersion

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url("https://repo.spring.io/milestone/")}
}

dependencies {
    runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
//    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy'
    implementation("org.apache.groovy:groovy:${groovyVersion}")

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation('com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:latest.integration')
    
    implementation group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
    
    implementation group: 'jakarta.persistence', name: 'jakarta.persistence-api', version: '3.1.0'

    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'
    testImplementation("org.testng:testng:${testNgVersion}")
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: also, I had to upgrade java compatibility. in the solution I used '17' for the source and target, and in fact, used the appropriate graalvm for java 17.